# Filter multiple Discord.js Presence Updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, discord, discord.js

When I use the following code:

```js
client.on(Events.PresenceUpdate, async (_, newUser )=>{
    console.log(newUser.user.id + "   " + newUser.activities[0]);
});
```

and change my status (message, playing, etc.), **the code runs multiple times** with slightly different *newUser* objects. What I want to get is only one object that holds the **latest** info about a user. Depending on my status message and activities, I get different numbers (like 3-5, or more triggers).
(it's important that I want to get the fully updated presence)
Is there an easy way to fix the issue?
Is there a way to distinguish multiple (bad) triggers from the one *newUser*, that actually holds the new presence?

I tried to solve the issue using a map that holds an id and a boolean value, but then I only get the first (with missing data) and not the last (fully updated) user.

I have one more idea, and that is to wait a second after the event, and then manually get the current status message. (but it would still trigger multiple times)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you show us what the console outputs after you change your states __one__ time?

Comment: When I switch from online to idle while "playing" VSCode:

442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   Visual Studio Code . . . 
442009521435574272   undefined

So I was wrong and the last is not the correct one.
( . . .  represents a newline)